# Split web traffic and email using DNS settings

Tags: dns

OK, I am an idiot when it comes to DNS settings but here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I need all web traffic to one of my sites to go to:
ns1.wordpress.com
ns2.wordpress.com
but all the email to:
ns6271.hostgator.com
ns6272.hostgator.com

Part of the problem is that both host's server IPs are dynamic so I have to use the nameservers, ugh.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use two sets of nameservers on the same domain. Simply put, that's not going to happen. However, it would be highly unusual if this was actually needed. Please describe the situation in more detail. // I quickly found instructions for Wordpress that do not need this, for example.

Answer (score 0):

When a browser access a Web server, it ask the DNS the Web server address (`A` or `CNAME` records. `A` for IP address, `CNAME` for a redirection to an other name).

When a mail server want to send mail to a domain, it asks the DNS its domain Mail server (`MX` records).

Then it is possible to redirect Web and mail to different servers even with same domain names.

These records typically looks like:

```
                         CNAME   my-www-server.my-domain.org.
www                      CNAME   my-www-server.my-domain.org.
a-server                 A       99.59.40.118
                         MX      10 my-mail-server.my-domain.org.
```

Implicitely, all lines are about the domain where they are declared. If the domain is `domain.org`, these lines define `domain.org`, `www.domain.org`, `a-server.domain.org`, and the last `domain.org` for mail exchange.

Note that a mail client (Outlook, Thunderbird...) will use `A` or `CNAME` records like the browser. Then you will have to use dedicated names (`mail.my-domain.org` for example). These names are only needed when setting the mailbox.

If a server is set with a dynamic address, you need to have a dynamic DNS. You can either use services like `dyndns.org` and redirect your domain with `CNAME` and `MX` records. Or (more complex) setup a DNS which accept dynamic changes.